# How to disable all days till today in Caldroid calendar?

Tags: android, caldroid

I'm using Caldroid library https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid. I want to disable all dates earlier than today. How can I do that? There is method setDisableDates, but it requires passing as argument list of dates to disable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution - use method setMinDate.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
 setMinDateTime(getToday());
```

use in customizeTextView() in CaldroidGridAdapter class